# Pagination in laravel gives me error "Undefined offset: 1"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

my controller code is

```
$enquiries = Enquiry::paginate(5);
return view('admin.enquiry-list')->withResults($enquiries);
```

my blade.php code is like this

```
{{ $enquiries->appends(Request::only('fullname',
            'mobile',
            'email'))->links() }}
```

where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does changing your code to this help at all? `return view('admin.enquiry-list', compact('enquiries));`

Comment: nope it is not improved

Comment: Are you using filters?

Comment: no not using any filters

Comment: So why are you appending `'fullname', 'mobile', 'email'` if those aren't filters?

Comment: there were timestamp fields which were null in my case therefore i tried this

Comment: in your view check if $enquiries  is not empty. if true then do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the links should not be treated as an html entity

```
 $enquiries = Enquiry::paginate(5);
    return view('admin.enquiry-list')->with('enquiries',$enquiries);

    {!! $enquiries->appends(Request::only('fullname',
                'mobile',
                'email'))->links() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to Laravel documentation, here Is what it says:

Appending To Pagination Links

You may append to the query string of pagination links using the appends method. For example, to append sort=votes to each pagination link, you should make the following call to appends:

```
{{ $users->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->links() }}
```

Based on it I feel what you are missing is Parameters supplied to the appends should be array. Can you try changing it to an **Array** ?

```
{{ $enquiries->appends(Request::only(['fullname',
        'mobile',
        'email']))->links() }}
```

Can you try checking if this works ?